# Recurring freqtrade bot error that I can't fix

Tags: cryptography, bots

I just started in freqtrade, I installed it with Docker. I don't understand why I get this error when I type in the terminal `docker-compose logs -f`:

> Config file "/freqtrade/user_data/config.json" not found! Please create a config file or check whether it exists)

Thank you for your help !

This is the code of my file docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  freqtrade:
    image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable
    # image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:develop
    # Use plotting image
    # image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:develop_plot
    # Build step - only needed when additional dependencies are needed
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   dockerfile: "./docker/Dockerfile.custom"
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: freqtrade
    volumes:
      - "./user_data:/freqtrade/user_data"
    # Expose api on port 8080 (localhost only)
    # Please read the https://www.freqtrade.io/en/latest/rest-api/ documentation
    # before enabling this.
    # ports:
    #   - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
    # Default command used when running `docker compose up`
    command: >
      trade
      --logfile /freqtrade/user_data/logs/freqtrade.log
      --db-url sqlite:////freqtrade/user_data/tradesv3.sqlite
      --config /freqtrade/user_data/config.json
      --strategy SampleStrategy
```

This is the code of my Terminal when I write docker-compose logs -f

```
Attaching to freqtrade
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:13,651 - freqtrade.worker - INFO - Starting worker 2021.6
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:13,652 - freqtrade.configuration.configuration - INFO - Using config: /Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json ...
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:13,652 - freqtrade.commands.trade_commands - ERROR - Config file "/Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json" not found! Please create a config file or check whether it exists.
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:13,652 - freqtrade.commands.trade_commands - ERROR - Fatal exception!
freqtrade    | Traceback (most recent call last):
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/load_config.py", line 58, in load_config_file
freqtrade    |     with open(path) if path != '-' else sys.stdin as file:
freqtrade    | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json'
freqtrade    | 
freqtrade    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
freqtrade    | 
freqtrade    | Traceback (most recent call last):
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/commands/trade_commands.py", line 18, in start_trading
freqtrade    |     worker = Worker(args)
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/worker.py", line 35, in __init__
freqtrade    |     self._init(False)
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/worker.py", line 49, in _init
freqtrade    |     self._config = Configuration(self._args, None).get_config()
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/configuration.py", line 41, in get_config
freqtrade    |     self.config = self.load_config()
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/configuration.py", line 92, in load_config
freqtrade    |     config: Dict[str, Any] = self.load_from_files(self.args.get("config", []))
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/configuration.py", line 73, in load_from_files
freqtrade    |     config = deep_merge_dicts(load_config_file(path), config)
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/load_config.py", line 61, in load_config_file
freqtrade    |     raise OperationalException(
freqtrade    | freqtrade.exceptions.OperationalException: Config file "/Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json" not found! Please create a config file or check whether it exists.
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:17,100 - freqtrade.worker - INFO - Starting worker 2021.6
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:17,100 - freqtrade.configuration.configuration - INFO - Using config: /Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json ...
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:17,106 - freqtrade.commands.trade_commands - ERROR - Config file "/Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json" not found! Please create a config file or check whether it exists.
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:17,107 - freqtrade.commands.trade_commands - ERROR - Fatal exception!
freqtrade    | Traceback (most recent call last):
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/load_config.py", line 58, in load_config_file
freqtrade    |     with open(path) if path != '-' else sys.stdin as file:
freqtrade    | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json'
freqtrade    | 
freqtrade    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
freqtrade    | 
freqtrade    | Traceback (most recent call last):
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/commands/trade_commands.py", line 18, in start_trading
freqtrade    |     worker = Worker(args)
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/worker.py", line 35, in __init__
freqtrade    |     self._init(False)
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/worker.py", line 49, in _init
freqtrade    |     self._config = Configuration(self._args, None).get_config()
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/configuration.py", line 41, in get_config
freqtrade    |     self.config = self.load_config()
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/configuration.py", line 92, in load_config
freqtrade    |     config: Dict[str, Any] = self.load_from_files(self.args.get("config", []))
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/configuration.py", line 73, in load_from_files
freqtrade    |     config = deep_merge_dicts(load_config_file(path), config)
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/load_config.py", line 61, in load_config_file
freqtrade    |     raise OperationalException(
freqtrade    | freqtrade.exceptions.OperationalException: Config file "/Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json" not found! Please create a config file or check whether it exists.
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:20,754 - freqtrade.worker - INFO - Starting worker 2021.6
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:20,754 - freqtrade.configuration.configuration - INFO - Using config: /Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json ...
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:20,755 - freqtrade.commands.trade_commands - ERROR - Config file "/Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json" not found! Please create a config file or check whether it exists.
freqtrade    | 2021-07-15 22:23:20,755 - freqtrade.commands.trade_commands - ERROR - Fatal exception!
freqtrade    | Traceback (most recent call last):
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/load_config.py", line 58, in load_config_file
freqtrade    |     with open(path) if path != '-' else sys.stdin as file:
freqtrade    | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json'
freqtrade    | 
freqtrade    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
freqtrade    | 
freqtrade    | Traceback (most recent call last):
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/commands/trade_commands.py", line 18, in start_trading
freqtrade    |     worker = Worker(args)
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/worker.py", line 35, in __init__
freqtrade    |     self._init(False)
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/worker.py", line 49, in _init
freqtrade    |     self._config = Configuration(self._args, None).get_config()
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/configuration.py", line 41, in get_config
freqtrade    |     self.config = self.load_config()
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/configuration.py", line 92, in load_config
freqtrade    |     config: Dict[str, Any] = self.load_from_files(self.args.get("config", []))
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/configuration.py", line 73, in load_from_files
freqtrade    |     config = deep_merge_dicts(load_config_file(path), config)
freqtrade    |   File "/freqtrade/freqtrade/configuration/load_config.py", line 61, in load_config_file
freqtrade    |     raise OperationalException(
freqtrade    | freqtrade.exceptions.OperationalException: Config file "/Users/ilanbacry/Desktop/bot/ft_userdata/user_data/config.json" not found! Please create a config file or check whether it exists.
```

Comment: Error clearly states "it cannot able to access the config file", you can either check the config file is available or specify the location using `--config` while using docker-compose up

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand how I can specify the location of the config file using docker-compose up. I don't know what I have to write in the Terminal

Comment: I don't understand because when I write --config in the Terminal, it sends me back that this command is not found. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Did you checked this link , this talks about configuration https://www.freqtrade.io/en/latest/docker_quickstart/

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand how to fix my problem. I can't find help at this link. Can you explain to me why when I write docker-compose up -d in terminal a new empty user_data file is being created? Thanks a lot